# Data retrieval failed for the subreport VB2012

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, subreport

I'm using VB2012 with Report Viewer 2012. I'm trying to get an order/orderdetail report. The ordernumbers are showing, but the subreport with orderdetails shows:"Data retrieval failed for the subreport".
I have a main report packingslip.rdlc that shows a list of order numbers. 
Under the order number I want the subreport PackingslipDetail.rdlc to show the order details for that order. In this subreport I created the parameter @prmOrderNumber.

Then I filled the value of the parameter by right click on the subreport/parameters.
Name: prmOrderNumber and Value: [OrderNumber]

Then I connected the report packingslip.rdlc to reportviewer1 in frm_Packingslip.vb. I connected its dataset packingslip, I just don't know what to write in the code. I read that I have to add the SubreportProcessingEventHandler, but I dont know how.

I got this:
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Public Class frm_Packingslip
Private Sub frm_Packingslip_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim instance As LocalReport = Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
Me.PackingSlipTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsTestStoneEdge.PackingSlip)
AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf Me.SubreportProcessingEventHandler
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
Public Sub SubreportProcessingEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
' Me.PackingslipDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsTestStoneEdge.PackingslipDetails)
e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("PackingslipDetail", Me.DsTestStoneEdge.PackingslipDetails))
End Sub
End Class

The line e.DataSources.Add etc. is not right to start with, probably amongst other errors. Please advise!

Hope that someone can get me on the right track!
Fernando